# How to find all values in - Array of plist?

Tags: objective-c, ios, for-loop

I hope this is clear and thanks in advance,

I would like to change the following line of code from get only values at index 0 to get the values at all existing indexs. I have to move from one array object in my Plist to many Array objects p.s. this line of code is in cellForRowAtIndexPath

```
    NSArray *myIndexList = [[inPlist objectAtIndex:0] objectForKey:@"myIndex"];
    NSLog( @"data from INDEX !!!!!!!! %@", myIndexList);
```

I've been toying with a for loop ....with no luck.
-Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your array is an array of dictionaries, which it seems to be since you're using objectForKey, you can just use valueForKey:

```
NSArray *myIndexList = [inPlist valueForKey:@"myIndex"];
```

This will give you all the values for the key "myIndex" in your array.

Answer (score 1):

enumerate the array.

for instance
- (void)enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:(void (^)(id obj, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop))block;

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, [fast enumeration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/ipad/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/objectivec/Chapters/ocFastEnumeration.html) would be a straightforward tactic.  The block-based approach recommended by user846262 is more advanced, but this is a bit easier at first.

Answer (score 0):

The fast enumeration is great, but not when you need to know the index of the item.

```
for(element *foo in array)
{
  // do stuff
}
```

vs

```
[array enumerateObjectUsingBlock:^(element *foo, NSUInteger i, BOOL *stop){
// here you got access to both foo and i, and it is working exactly the same way for loop does

}];
```

HTH